# How to use EntityManager instance in interface using default methods of Java 8?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, java-8, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to implement the default method in the interface of the Spring Data repository. Is there any way we can use an instance of default EntityManager in the interface in Java 8.

Following is the desired implementation which I want to do.

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {

   @PersistenceContext
   EntityManager em;

   default List<Customer> findCustomersByCity(String city){
       Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE city = ?1", Customer.class);
       query.setParameter("city",city);
       return query.getResultList();
   }
```

}

Is there any way we can implement such a design? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not as interface default methods, but you can write your custom plain JPA based implementation of repository interfaces.
See [CustomerRepository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-book/blob/master/jpa/src/main/java/com/oreilly/springdata/jpa/core/CustomerRepository.java) and [JpaCustomerRepository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-book/blob/master/jpa/src/main/java/com/oreilly/springdata/jpa/core/JpaCustomerRepository.java) implementations in Spring Data Book samples.

Check for more information Spring Data reference:
[4.6. Custom Implementations for Spring Data Repositories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations)

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I will definitely try out this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any custom implementation for that method. Let Spring generate it for you:

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {
  
    List<Customer> findAllByCity(String city);

}
```

The only thing you need is to tweak the method name a little bit letting Spring to understand it.

Comment: Actually I need to extend functionality of JPA repository with our own custom methods. This example is for illustration purposes only. Some database specific operation requires custom methods.

Comment: Then [Cem Ikta's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62801522/10584605) is what can point you to the right direction.

Comment: Can you give an example of **database specific** operation you want to implement?

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I will try the Plain Repository solution as that suites my requirement.